# Bottom Navigation View : never select menu item when startup

Tags: android, menuitem, startup

how to make the bottom navigation menu no select any menu item when startup the application??

i am trying to set

`bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);`

but this is not working..

this is the layout i want

[image]

Comment: why not...`bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false)`...?

Comment: hi, i updated my question already

Answer (score 0):

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.myTabId);
```

You can use this code to select a option programmatically at start.